# Logging not working in .NET 6 Azure Functions with the default code provided by Visual Studio 2022

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps, azureservicebus, asp.net-core-6.0

### Code Snippets:

**host.json**

```json
{
    "version": "2.0",
    "logging": {
        "applicationInsights": {
            "samplingSettings": {
                "isEnabled": true,
                "excludedTypes": "Request"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Function Code**:

```cs
public class SBFuncTrigger
    {
        private readonly ILogger<Function1> _logger;

        public Function1(ILogger<Function1> log)
        {
            _logger = log;
        }

        [FunctionName("SBFuncTrigger")]
        public void Run([ServiceBusTrigger("sampletopic", "sbtopicsubscription", Connection = "ServiceBusConnStr")]string mySbMsg)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation($"C# ServiceBus topic trigger function processed message: {mySbMsg}");
        }
    }
```

**Output**:

```
For detailed output, run func with --verbose flag.
 Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '<Some_Id>'.
 Executing 'SBFuncTrigger' (Reason='(null)', Id=
<Some_Id>)
 Trigger Details: MessageId: 
<Some_Id>, SequenceNumber: 8, DeliveryCount: 1, EnqueuedTimeUtc: , LockedUntilUtc: , SessionId: (null)
 Executed 'Function1' (Succeeded, Id=
<Some_Id>, Duration=xxxms)
```

**I'm not getting the msg in output**:

```cs
C# ServiceBus topic trigger function processed message: {mySbMsg}
```

### Details/Implementation:

1. Created logic app for sending message to topic subscription with content "Hello to Azure Functions Service Bus"
   [image]
2. Azure Functions Service Bus Topic Trigger - created with a topic and subscription in the Azure Portal Service Bus Namespace.
3. Logic App Workflow connected to Service Bus Topic Subscription for message transfer.
4. Connection string of service bus `ServiceBusConnStr` is defined in `local.settings.json`

Comment: Does Logic App Workflow read from the same topic?

Comment: ServiceBusTrigger is normally used for the Function:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus-trigger?tabs=in-process%2Cextensionv5&pivots=programming-language-csharp

Comment: Yes @MarkusMeyer, Logic App Workflow is designed to the same topic given in the Service Bus Trigger Function Declaration Code.

Comment: Hello @codebrane, Service Bus Trigger can receive the message from the Logic App designed with When a http request is received (Logic App Runs) >  Send a message to Service Bus Topic specified. I have given implementation in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’re missing the **ILogger** Class in the Function Declaration of the Service Bus Trigger you have provided.

```cs
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace KrishSBNet6FunctionApp
{
    public class Function1
    {
        private readonly ILogger<Function1> _logger;
        public Function1(ILogger<Function1> log)
        {
            _logger = log;
        }

        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public void Run([ServiceBusTrigger("messagetopic", "topicsubsn", Connection = "SBConnection")] string mySbMsg, ILogger _logger)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation($"C# ServiceBus topic trigger function processed message: {mySbMsg}");
        }
    }
}
```

[image]